# Android: Communication between Activity and Fragment Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, interface

I have a normal android activity which contains a list view of choices. When a choice is selected it starts a Fragment Activity via an intent. This fragment activity itself contains an action bar and consists of 3 fragments.

**What i want to do is based on the selection on the activity (which contains the list view of 
choices) is to send the selected position number to the fragment activity and thus the 3 fragments**

I found out about interfaces but the examples are confusing to understand, can someone help me out here. I just want to send the selected position to the other fragments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing the selected position from the Activity to the FragmentActivity can be done with `Bundle`

Your Intent should look like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, FragmentActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("idforthevalue",selectedPOsition);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then on your FragmentActivity you can retrieve the value:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int position = 0;
    if(extras != null) {
        position = extras.getInt("idforthevalue");
    }
```

And the depending on how you are adding your fragments you can also pass this value to them with Bundle from the FragmentActivity in a `FragmentTransaction`

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();  // or getSupportFragmentManager() if you are using compat lib
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

FragmentX fragmentX = new FragmentX();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("idforthevalue", position);
fragmentX.setArguments(bundle);

fragmentTransaction.replace(id_of_container, fragmentX).commit();
```

And again you can retrieve the value in the fragment

```
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if(bundle != null) {
            position = bundle.getInt("idforthevalue", 0);
        }
```

You can do the same for the three Fragments.